# Queuing BankgroundJob with Hangfire within an async action in ASP.NET MVC freeze the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, task-parallel-library, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I have this action on one of my controllers which is called by another method which has been called also by another action.

All works fine, unless I try to en-queue with  `Hangfire` some jobs: `_bankClient.FetchAndEnsureTransactionsAsync` and `_bankClient.RefreshItemAsync`.
This is causing the application to freeze (the client, browser, stops while the server is still running). I suppose is some weird `deadlock`, but nothing I've tried seems to make it work!

Would someone know how to solve this problem?

I'm aware `Hangfire` does not support yet calling `async` methods, so I have the `synchronous` version of this methods which I en-queue.

**NOT** working action

```
private async Task<ActionResult> ActionOnFinished(long itemId, ItemStatus status, Guid userId)
    {
        var seller = await _unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.GetCompanyByUserIdAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _bankClient.CreateItemAndAccountsAsync(userId, seller.Id, itemId, seller.Name, seller.Siren.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // TODO: use hangfire when available and fire this on BackgroundJob
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.EnableHangfire)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Schedule<IBankClientService>(bs => bs.FetchAndEnsureTransactions(userId), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1));
            BackgroundJob.Schedule<IBankClientService>(bs => bs.RefreshItem(userId), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1));
        }
        else
        {
            await _bankClient.FetchAndEnsureTransactionsAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await _bankClient.RefreshItemAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Dashboard.MyProfile());
    }
```

**Working** action :

```
 private async Task<ActionResult> ActionOnFinished(long itemId, ItemStatus status, Guid userId)
    {
        var seller = await _unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.GetCompanyByUserIdAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _bankClient.CreateItemAndAccountsAsync(userId, seller.Id, itemId, seller.Name, seller.Siren.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // TODO: use hangfire when available and fire this on BackgroundJob
        await _bankClient.FetchAndEnsureTransactionsAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _bankClient.RefreshItemAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Dashboard.MyProfile());
    }
```

The precedent action is called by a private method:

```
private async Task<ActionResult> SelectActionByStatus(long itemId, ItemStatus status, Guid userId)
    {
        try
        {                
            if (status.Status == RefreshStatusValues.Finished)
            {
                return await ActionOnFinished(itemId, status, userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return ActionOnError();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, nameof(SelectBank));
            throw new ValidationFailureException(nameof(GetAccounts), ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This action has been called by another action:

```
public async virtual Task<ActionResult> CallBack(string item_id)
    {
        try
        {
            var itemId = long.Parse(item_id);

            var userId = CurrentUserId.Value;
            // as this action is being called by a child window whom is being closed we need to configure the awaiter with ConfigureAwait(false)
            var status = await _bankClient.CheckItemStatusAsync(userId, itemId).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await SelectActionByStatus(itemId, status, userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, nameof(CallBack));
            return RedirectToAction(MVC.Bank.BankError());
        }
    }
```

**SYNCHRONOUS VERSION:** being enqueued:

```
public IEnumerable<Transaction> FetchAndEnsureTransactions(Guid userId)
    {
        try
        {
            return FetchAndEnsureTransactionsAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, $"{nameof(FetchAndEnsureTransactions)}");
            throw;
        }
    }

public void RefreshItem(Guid userId)
    {
        try
        {
            RefreshItemAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, $"{nameof(RefreshItem)}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```